# How can I convert and encode date correctly for $resource get request using Angular 1?

Tags: angularjs, swagger, encode

My form input looks like:

startDate: Wed Aug 02 2017 17:14:16 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) 
endDate: Wed Aug 02 2017 17:14:16 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

Swagger Input looks like: Tue, 18 Jul 2017 13:15:30 GMT

When I encode "Tue, 18 Jul 2017 13:15:30 GMT" using encodeURI() I am getting: Tue,%2018%20Jul%202017%2013:15:30%20GMT, however, swagger encodes it as "Tue%2C%2018%20Jul%202017%2013%3A15%3A30%20GMT"

Swagger request url looks like:
http://xxxx/abcd/consumption/TX/flexobject-test/timeRange?start_time=Tue%2C%2018%20Jul%202017%2013%3A15%3A30%20GMT&end_time=Tue%2C%2018%20Jul%202017%2013%3A15%3A30%20GMT&storage_unit=GB

Problems:

1. Needs to convert Wed Aug 02 2017 17:14:16 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) like Tue, 18 Jul 2017 13:15:30 GMT.
2. Needs to encode like swagger encoder using Angular for $resource http get request.

Comment: have you trie $filter date, or sanitize the value with new Date()

Comment: The first, more verbose string looks like the default format of a date (ie: new Date()). If you want the time in GMT, then a new date would be new Date().toUTCString(). So assuming that (first date) is a date object, just call .toUTCString(). You could try calling new Date("string_date"), but it's not always a safe solution (browser compatibility issues).

Comment: Great, date filter is helpful. Thank you.